# Getting false warning message for a newer version of the Picasso library in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, picasso

I am seeing a warning message in Android Studio when I use the Picasso library in my Android project. The warning message says

> **A newer version of com.squareup.picasso:picasso than 2.8 is available: 2.71828**
> [image: See screenshot of Android Studio's warning.]

even though version 2.8 is the latest official version according to the official Picasso version history.

I have already tried adding the latest version of Picasso to my Gradle build file using the following line:`implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.8'`

I found in Picasso's version history that version 2.71828 was published 5 years ago and version 2.8 was published 2 years ago.
[image: Screenshot of Picasso's version history.]

I have also tried cleaning and rebuilding my project, but the warning message still persists.

Comment: You might want to look for an alternative, Picasso seems abandoned.

Comment: @LawrenceGimenez Thanks for your reply. Please provide information on alternative libraries.
What could be the alternative to the Picasso library?
Your answer will benefit me a lot.

Comment: We are using Coil in production, previously we used Glide but we were having issues with building it via Gradle.

Comment: Another option is Fresco.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**This issue has already been discussed on [GitHub](https://github.com/square/picasso/issues/2179#issue-676616837).**
**It is said there:**

> Updated Picasso version 2.71828 to 2.8. Now Android Lint complains that there is a newer version 2.71828 available. Which is true in semantic versioning sense since 71828 > 8.
>
> One can suppress the GradleDependency lint check for the library to
> get rid of the warning. However, I would find it better if version
> number components were monotonically increasing instead.

Android Studio often gives such false suggestions. No need to worry about it.

But you can remove the warning. If you want to suppress it, write this line:

```
//noinspection GradleDependency
```

**The complete code will look like this:**

```
//noinspection GradleDependency
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.8'
```